# Поиск строки по слову

Tags: c++builder, массивы

У меня есть файл,в котором содержится библиотека. В каждой строчке написан автор,название книги,год издания и издатель. Мне нужно по введенному слову найти необходимую строку с считываемого файла. Как мне это сделать на с++? Через массив? Как считывать из файла я знаю,просто не знаю как реализовать поиск

Comment: Лучше всего почитать о классе `std::string` и его методе `find`.

Comment: А можете порекомендовать литературу

Comment: Наберите в гугле

    c++ string find

и читайте.

Answer (score 1):

1) Считываете из файла строку

2) Ищете в ней вхождение слова

Comment: У меня там несколько книг. Я считываю из файла все строки,которые там записаны. А дальше как мне найти по слову нужную мне строчку,например из 5 строк написанных в файле

Comment: Просто подсчитывайте в процессе чтения номера строк в файле и печатайте текущий номер, если слово найдено в строке.

Comment: Мне нужно ввести слово,а по нему найти строку.по заданию я не могу вводить номер строки. Например,у меня телефонный справочник,то я создаю массив,и по имени нахожу номер. А как быть здесь? Я не знаю указать в цикле for. С телефоном там указал ограничения и всё,а как быть здесь?

Comment: @Димка-10, не уверен, что на самом деле хорошо понимаю Ваши вопросы, но IMHO никакие массивы в подобных задачах не нужны.

Можно делать примерно так:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
      string p = av[1] ? av[1] : "xaxa", s;
    
      for (int i = 0; getline(cin, s); i++) 
        if (s.find(p) != string::npos)
          cout << i + 1 << " : " << s << '\n';

    }
    
Читаете файл посторочно в цикле. Смотрите есть ли искомое слово в очередной строке. Печатаете номер строки (и ее саму).